# Reading gscript file with Colab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-colaboratory, eoserror

Imagine I got some gscript file sitting in my Google Drive in some Test folder. I can see it from Colab like so:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import os
files = os.listdir("drive/My Drive/Test") 
files
['Test_app.gscript']
```

However, I tried some options to read *Test_app.gscript*, but all of them have given me *OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: 'drive/My Drive/Test/Test_app.gscript'*

Is there a way to read this slippery *gscript* doc?

Comment: Use the Google Apps Script API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent

Comment: Is Google Apps Script API really that confusing as it looks to me from the first glance, or it actually is very confusing?